# CommandBinding Executed event handler not called when using custom ICommand implementation

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to undestand how RoutedUICommand Works. I have worked with MVVM in Wpf, and was trying to under stand ICommand implementation actually works in wpf. However, I am unable to understand something.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<Task> callBack;
    private bool runOnUi;
    private Action<object> whatToExecute;
    private Func<object, bool> whenToExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Func<object, bool> whenToExecute, Action<object> whatToExecute,
        bool runOnUi = true, Action<Task> callBack = null)
    {
        this.whenToExecute = whenToExecute;
        this.whatToExecute = whatToExecute;
        this.runOnUi = runOnUi;
        this.callBack = callBack;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is an event from Interface
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Decides whether the command can execute or not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.whenToExecute != null)
        {
            try
            {
                return this.whenToExecute(parameter);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when CanExecute is true and command is fired.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.whatToExecute != null)
        {
            if (this.runOnUi)
            {
                this.whatToExecute(parameter);
            }
            else
            {
                var parallelTask = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    this.whatToExecute(parameter);
                });
                if (this.callBack != null)
                    parallelTask.ContinueWith(this.callBack);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the custom implementation of ICommand interface.
I have added two menuitems to context menu of label. First with ApplicationCommands.Close and second on with my customer RelayCommand type.

```
    this.Label1.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

    var menuItem1 = new MenuItem();//Source
    menuItem1.Command = ApplicationCommands.Close; //Command

    var commandBindingObject = new CommandBinding(menuItem1.Command);
    commandBindingObject.CanExecute += this.MenuItem1Close_CanExecute;
    commandBindingObject.Executed += this.MenuItem1Close_Executed;
    menuItem1.CommandBindings.Add(commandBindingObject);

    var menuItem2 = new MenuItem();//Source
    menuItem2.Header = "Custom Command";
    menuItem2.Command = new RelayCommand(o =>
    {
        return true;
    },
        o =>
        {
        }); //Command

    var commandBindingObject2 = new CommandBinding(menuItem2.Command);
    commandBindingObject2.CanExecute += this.MenuItem2Close_CanExecute;
    commandBindingObject2.Executed += this.MenuItem2Close_Executed;
    menuItem2.CommandBindings.Add(commandBindingObject2);

    this.Label1.ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem1);
    this.Label1.ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem2);
```

Whenever I click the first menu item handler is menuitem1 handler for executed is called, but not for the  menuitem2. I am just trying to understand how command pattern is implemented in wpf, so in addition any links to such would also be of great help.

Comment: Whats in these event handlers? `MenuItem2Close_CanExecute` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Routed Commands

The `ApplicationCommands.Close` command is a `RoutedUICommand`. [Routed commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview) raise the [`PreviewExecuted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.commandbinding.previewexecuted?view=netcore-3.1) and [`Executed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.commandbinding.executed?view=netcore-3.1) routed events which traverse the element tree until they find a command binding. If one is found the corresponding `ExecutedRoutedEventHandler` is called. In case of `menuItem1` the executed handler is `MenuItem1Close_Executed`. The same applies to the `PreviewCanExecute` and `CanExecute` events and the `MenuItem1Close_CanExecute` handler as `CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler`.

### Relay Commands

Your `menuItem2` uses a `RelayCommand`. This type of command uses delegates for `CanExecute` and `Execute`, instead of traversing the element tree in search for command bindings.

In your case the following lines are unnecessary.

```
var commandBindingObject2 = new CommandBinding(menuItem2.Command);
commandBindingObject2.CanExecute += this.MenuItem2Close_CanExecute;
commandBindingObject2.Executed += this.MenuItem2Close_Executed;
menuItem2.CommandBindings.Add(commandBindingObject2);
```

Instead pass methods or anonymous methods for `whenToExecute` and `whatToExecute`.

```
menuItem2.Command = new RelayCommand(CanExecute, Execute);
```

You cannot pass `MenuItem1Close_CanExecute` or `MenuItem1Close_Executed` here, because they have incompatible signatures:

```
void CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
void ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
```

`CanExecute` has to be a `Func<object, bool>` and `Execute` has to be an `Action<object>` delegate.

```
bool CanExecute(object obj)
void Execute(object obj)
```